# How to insert array of nested json in a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

We have a user data that is fetched from an api(a third party) and from that data we need to store the data into a table using postgresql.

I am passing in json data from an API to the Postgres function tests. The data represents new users of my application and contains the data I want to insert into the users table (if the record does not already exist)

### Below is my code.

```
with recursive jsondata AS(
    SELECT 
        data ->0->>'rmid' as rmid,
        data ->0->>'camid' as camid,
        data ->0->'userlist' as children 
    FROM (
        SELECT '[{"rmid":1,"camid":2,"userlist":[{"userid":34,"username":33},{"userid":35,"username":36}]},{"rmid":3,"camid":4,"userlist":[{"userid":44,"username":43},{"userid":44,"username":43}]}]'::jsonb as data
    ) s
    
    UNION 
    
    SELECT
        value ->0->> 'rmid',
        value ->0->> 'camid',
        value ->0-> 'children'
    FROM jsondata,jsonb_array_elements(jsondata.children)
    )SELECT 
    rmid,camid,
    jsonb_array_elements(children) ->> 'userid' as userid,
    jsonb_array_elements(children) ->> 'username' as username
FROM jsondata WHERE children IS NOT NULL
```

### The output I am getting

[image]

### The output I expect

[image]
I need the object of the array at all the index in table, How do I achieve that?I
Please help

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly is the problem. You have a table with JSONB column and you store some values in this column and then you fetch/select those values back. I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: I need the object at index 2 of the array to get inserted in the table too.

Comment: Aren't you already inserting the whole array with all of its indexes?

Comment: data ->0->>'rmid' as rmid,
      data ->0->>'camid' as camid,
        data ->0->'userlist' as children, 
I am inserting only the 0th index, How do I access all the index

Comment: Just like you do with the 0th index - simply replace 0 with 2. Or, just store the whole JSON from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need recursive query here, json processing functions are enough to achieve your desired output:

> ```
> create table test(
>   rmid int,
>   camid int,
>   userid int,
>   username text
> );
>
> insert into test
> select 
>   (a->>'rmid')::int rmid,
>   (a->>'camid')::int camid,
>   (b->>'userid')::int userid,
>   b->>'username' username
> from (
> select '[{"rmid":1,"camid":2,"userlist":[{"userid":34,"username":33},{"userid":35,"username":36}]},{"rmid":3,"camid":4,"userlist":[{"userid":44,"username":43},{"userid":44,"username":43}]}]'::jsonb as data
> ) j 
> cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j.data) a
> cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(a->'userlist') b
> ;
>
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> rmid | camid | userid | username
> ---: | ----: | -----: | :-------
>    1 |     2 |     34 | 33      
>    1 |     2 |     35 | 36      
>    3 |     4 |     44 | 43      
>    3 |     4 |     44 | 43
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cdb3dc1fcae5032ea33a0685f538e76)*

Comment: What should I do to insert this into a table?

Comment: @NitinKumar, see the edit with the example of `INSERT`. I don't know what your table look like, but assuming that `id`s are integers you would need some casting (`::int`).